# É possível definir um tamanho para os slices do AmFunnelChart?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um dashboard para exibir os dados do cliente e tive a ideia de utilizar o `AmFunnelChart` para criar um funil de informações de um fluxo de operação do usuário.

Mas quando eu gero um funil qualquer com dados muito altos, ele acaba ficando muito desproporcional. Teria como eu definir um tamanho fixo?

Dei uma olhada na propriedade `valueRepresents`, mas qualquer informação que eu definia nele, não executava da forma que eu gostaria.

Exemplo de exibição:

[image: EXEMPLO]